# Any real disadvantage to extra markup created by jQuery rounded corners?

Tags: html, markup, rounded-corners

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/

Is there any real disadvantage (like SEO) to creating the rounded corners pixel by pixel using javascript generated DIVs other than being an eye-sore when looking at the markup?

Comment: The generated HTML is not visible when looking at the source, as it is only generated using JS.

Comment: Can I say this is the best industry-standard javascript solution for rounded corners for IE? as compared to making a http request for background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not give you any SEO problems, but it will almost certainly result in a performance hit. Much better to just use CSS3 properties for browsers which support `border-radius` properties, and leave borders square for other, less capable browsers.

Answer (score 2):

There will be no noticeable SEO hit.  No one can say 100%, but it's 99.999% likely that this will not affect SEO in any way at all.